# jsf2 search bean request scope is not displaying results

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces, jsf-2.2

Here is my code,

search.xhtml  page

```
<h:form id="searchform">
        <h:inputText id="deptId" value="#{searchBean.departmentId}"></h:inputText>
        <h:inputText id="deptName" value="#{searchBean.deparmentName}"></h:inputText>
        <h:commandButton value="Click to Search" action="#{searchBean.searchEmployees}">
        </h:commandButton>       
    </h:form>
```

searchresults.xhtml   page

```
<rich:dataTable value="#{searchBean.employeeList}" var="e" id="table">
            <rich:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="FNAME"/>
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{e.fName}"/>
            </rich:column> 
            <rich:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="LNAME"/>
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{e.lName}"/>
            </rich:column>
        <rich:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="DEPARTMENT"/>
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{e.dept}"/>
            </rich:column>          
 </rich:dataTable>
```

In the managed bean

```
ManagedBean

@ManagedBean(name="searchBean")
@RequestScoped
public class SearchBean implements Serializable{

    private String departmentId;
    private String deparmentName;
    private List<EmpBean> employeeList;

    //....get/set 's

    public String searchEmployees(){
        employeeList = service.getEmployees(departmentId,deparmentName);
         return "searchresults.xhtml";
    }
```

Issue: searchresults page is is not displaying records though it fetched records from table 
    I'm able to achieve this using search bean as session scope but i want to use the scope as Requestscope, bec of performance.
    Please suggest...!

Comment: @Makky - that's awful advice. The session scope is hardly ever a good candidate for a page-backing bean

Answer (score 3):

**The Problem**

The reason you're not seeing the results is because you have an incorrect understanding of the `@RequestScope` and consequently, improbable expectations of the scope

`searchEmployees` executes during the `INVOKE_APPLICATION` phase, the second to the last phase of the JSF request processing lifecycle. By the time the user is redirected to *searchResults.xhtml*, the instance of your `SearchBean` that holds the search results has been destroyed and a brand new one created, resulting in an empty list.

This is the rule for every bean scope except the `@SessionScoped`: a navigation action will cause the old bean to be destroyed and a new one created. This is not to say that `@SessionScoped` should be your scope of choice (it's generally a terrible idea to back a page with a `@SessionScoped` bean).

---

**The Solution**

Use the [`FlashScope`](https://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.0/javadocs/javax/faces/context/Flash.html) to temporarily stash the results just for display on the other page. For example

```
employeeList = service.getEmployees(departmentId,deparmentName);
Flash theFlashScope = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getFlash();
      theFlashScope.put("searchResults",employeeList);
      return "searchresults.xhtml";
```

Then in *searchResults.xhtml*

```
<rich:dataTable value="#{flash.searchResults}" var="e" id="table">
```

Here, `#{flash}` is an implicit EL object; you don't have to do anything else.

**EDIT:** Based on your "answer", you should be aware that the `Flash` object keeps variables stored in it for only the first render of the page. Subsequent HTTP requests will clear the content of the flash object.

If you're interested in keeping the content of the flash object beyond the first render, you should use the `Flash#keep`:

```
<rich:dataTable value="#{flash.keep.searchResults}" var="e" id="table">
```

**Further Reading**

- [Max Katz's blog on the Flash object](http://mkblog.exadel.com/2010/07/learning-jsf2-using-flash-scope/)