# What is the best way to display results in another page

Tags: primefaces, richfaces, jsf-2.2, primefaces-extensions

I have a link tag, onclick of this link i want to show the results in another page

Any sample code will be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jsf2 search bean request scope is not displaying results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23307336/jsf2-search-bean-request-scope-is-not-displaying-results)

Answer (score 0):

You have bunch of examples here:
http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/4-ways-to-pass-parameter-from-jsf-page-to-backing-bean/

And this page will be also interesting for you: 
http://incepttechnologies.blogspot.com/p/view-parameters-in-jsf-20.html